If every totally bounded and closed set is compact, is the space complete?
I know a well-known result that if every closed and bounded set is compact, then the whole space is complete. I wonder if this is true when a stricter condition is imposed, that is, only every totally bounded and closed set is compact. If not, do we have a counter example?
Thank you for your help!

ohh goodness, terrible mistake by me

@peek-a-boo, no problem ^^, all fun, it's nice to have someone to interact with!

The answer is yes: if every totally bounded closed subset in $X$ is compact, then $X$ is complete. (In fact, the opposite statement is also true, so this is a criterion of completeness)
Assume that $X$ is not complete. Then there is a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ that does not converge in $X$. We check that $A = \{x_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$ is a closed and totally bounded subset in $X$. Indeed, for $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that the set $\{x_n: n \ge N\}$ has diameter $\le \varepsilon$. Thus, since $A = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{N-1}\{x_k\} \cup \{x_n: n \ge N\}$, $A$ can be represented as a finite union of sets of arbitrary small diameter, i.e. $A$ is totally bounded. Now assume that $A$ is not closed and take $x \in \overline{A} \setminus A$. It is easy to see that there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ in $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ that converges to $x$. But then we conclude that $x_n \rightarrow x$, since it is a Cauchy sequence (if a subsequence in a Cauchy sequence converges, then the whole sequence converges to the same limit). We arrived at a contradiction, so $A$ is closed. Finally, we can conclude that $A$ is compact, and, therefore, a subsequence in $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges, and so does the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Basically, the set supporting a nonconvergent Cauchy sequence is closed and totally bounded. Therefore a noncomplete space cannot have the stated property.
